# Find pairs of teams that played against each other most number of times

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have the following table called Involves:

```
match  |  team
10     |  A
10     |  B
20     |  B
20     |  C
30     |  C
30     |  A
40     |  D
40     |  C
50     |  A
50     |  B
```

The values in the column 'match' refer to the unique id of the match and the values in the column 'team' refer to the unique id of the team.

I am trying to write a query that will output the pair of teams that have played the most matches against each other. 
The output show look like the following:

```
team1  |  team2  |  matches
A      |  B      |  2
```

Since A and B have played against each other in two matches, matches 10 and 50.

To solve this problem, I am thinking that you would have to find all possible team pair combinations and then find the total number of matches each pair has played against each other. From this result set, you can select the tuples that have the maximum value for the total matches played. However, I am not sure how I can go about writing such a query, especially with regards to finding all pair combinations. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT team1
     , team2
     , COUNT(*) AS matches_played
FROM (
    SELECT match
         , MIN(team) AS team1
         , MAX(team) AS team2
    FROM t
    GROUP BY match
) AS x
GROUP BY team1, team2
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

The inner query is used to generate ordered pairs such as `(a, b)`, `(a, c)` and `(b, c)`.

Comment: Isn't `match` a keyword ?

Comment: Quote it. I am unfamiliar with pgsql.

Comment: @cid: it's a keyword, but not a reserved one. So you can use it without quoting.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregating the teams for a match into an array makes processing the results a bit easier:

```
select teams[1] as team1, 
       teams[2] as team2, 
       count
from (       
  select teams, 
         count(*) as count,  
         dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
  from (
    select match, array_agg(team order by team) as teams
    from matches
    group by match
  ) t1
  group by teams
) t2
where rnk = 1;
```

The inner most query aggregates the teams for each match into an array, the next level determines the team combination with the highest count using `dense_rank()` and the outer most query then selects those with the highest 
count displays the two teams and the count of matches.

Online example: https://rextester.com/FTOA17246

Comment: I think the use of `dense_rank()` is a better match for the problem, because the question suggests that multiple pairs might meet the condition.